# Indexing a matrix by column/row when it might become length 1

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, vector, indexing

I want to index a matrix m*n by specifing row and column but when the m or n becomes 1, you cant index it as a matrix but as a vector:

```
M=matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2)
M[1,] #Works
M=M[-1,]
M[1,] #Doesn't work
```

Is there any workaround instead of using if/else to check for the length of m/n?

Comment: You can use the `drop` argument to avoid losing a dimension. E.g. `M[-1, drop = FALSE]` returns a matrix while `M[-1, ]` is coerced to a vector. See `?"["` for details.

Comment: I meant: `M[-1, , drop = FALSE]` (the second comma matters).